# Port Java to JavaScript - Secretkeyspec

Tags: javascript, java

Can anyone give me any leads as to how to convert the following JAVA code to Javascript?

```
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
mac.init(secretKeySpec);
byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes());
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();        
return encoder.encodeBuffer(rawHmac).trim();
```

Comment: You could look into using CryptoJS: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

Comment: You cannot directly convert this into JavaScript. You need to find related library or plugins in js

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to convert Java code to Javascript directly. If you are looking for a simple converter that would automatcally convert your Java logic or functions into Javascript ...then it doesn't exist.

You may have to find the appropriate libraries and functions in Javascript. And then write new fresh code which would implement the same logic in Javascript.

Having said that, [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) is a good matured javascript library that supports the various crypto standards. Please refer it and write your code in Javascript.

By looking at your Java code , I believe that you are trying to encrypt a piece of text using a secret key. Please have a look at the code below written in Javascript :

```
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);


function  encrypt(){
  console.log('salt  '+ salt );
  console.log('iv  '+ iv );
  var key128Bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("Secret Passphrase", salt, { keySize: 128/32 }); 
  console.log( 'key128Bits '+ key128Bits);
  var key128Bits100Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("Secret Passphrase", salt, { keySize: 128/32, iterations: 100 });
  console.log( 'key128Bits100Iterations '+ key128Bits100Iterations);
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key128Bits100Iterations, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7  });
  console.log('encrypted   '+ encrypted  );
}



function  decrypt(encrypted){
 // var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("4acfedc7dc72a9003a0dd721d7642bde");
 // var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("69135769514102d0eded589ff874cacd");
 // var encrypted = "PU7jfTmkyvD71ZtISKFcUQ==";
  console.log('salt  '+ salt );
  console.log('iv  '+ iv );
  var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("Secret Passphrase", salt, { keySize: 128/32, iterations: 100 });
  console.log( 'key '+ key);
  var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
  var ddd = decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); 
  console.log('ddd '+ddd);
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much. I actually used Crypto_js to get it up and running!

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)! and run whatever java processing you have to do, on your Java server. If secretKey is something that changes each time you could pass the bytes via base64 encoding and decode the bytes on the server. If it's something that just needs to be available to js initially, you can have the server just output:

```
<script>myvalue = "bytes here"'</script>
```

into the page for js use.